# How to integrate Moengage in Node js API's to send email notification on user action?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, adonis.js, moengage

Is there any way to integrate Moengage in Node Js API's to send notification to the user on user event?

I go through the Moengage API docs but didn't get any relevant information to integrate Moengage in Node Js API?
Is there any step by step guide to user Moengage in node js API?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

MoEngage does not have NodeJS SDK currently. If you have a web application or mobile application, then you can integrate the SDK and automate this logic in the MoEngage dashboard using the Event Triggered campaigns.

If you have to invoke through your NodeJS code, then you will have to either use the transactional API called [Inform](https://developers.moengage.com/hc/en-us/articles/10699624590868-Inform-API) or call their [Data API](https://developers.moengage.com/hc/en-us/articles/4413174113044-Bulk-Import) to send the events (similar to the SDKs sending it). In the case of Data API, you need to configure the Event Triggered campaign using the MoEngage dashboard. My recommendation would be to use Inform API, especially if the use case is transactional in nature, like order created, OTP, etc.